# WordPress URLs don't work locally

Tags: apache, wordpress, macos

I have a WordPress site running on a production server that I recently copied to my Mac. When I want to view the site on my Mac, I go here and it works fine:

```
http://localhost/jasonswett.net/web/
```

But then when I try to view any post it doesn't work. If I go here

```
http://localhost/jasonswett.net/web/tar-examples/
```

I get an error that says, "The requested URL /jasonswett.net/web/tar-examples/ was not found on this server."

I know mod_rewrite is enabled because I see it when I do a `phpinfo()`. My htaccess file is a straight copy from production.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you try to remove the last '/' at the end of the url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the AllowOverride directive is not properly set for that folder. In your Apache configuration, you should make sure that the Directory or Vhost you're using for the primary domain has the AllowOverride set to All

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated the wordpress location configurations in your database that you copied?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://old.net','http://new.net');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://old.net', 'http://new.net');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://old.net', 'http://new.net');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://old.net', 'http://new.net');
```

This is a necessary step when moving wordpress from one domain to another, including production to local.

Otherwise, have you checked that your .htaccess on local is being read at all? Try setting a PHP configuration value in it and seeing if it is picked up by phpinfo(). There are a lot of ways this could be wrong:
1. You may need to adjust the ownership of .htaccess to the user your apache runs as with `chown` and `chmod 640` it as well so read permissions will be granted for owner and group.
2. You may need to set the AllowOverride directive in your httpd.conf
3. Check that you have not modified AccessFileName directive.

Last, what happens if you disable permalinks in wordpress?

Comment: I ran those statements and it still doesn't work. It's a server 404, not a WP error.

Comment: Try checking if your .htaccess is being used, as my edit recommends.

Comment: It seems that it's not being used. I don't know how to change a PHP config value with Apache but I changed some of the .htaccess syntax to something invalid and I didn't get any errors.